# Strange behavior with Regex pattern

Tags: regex

I'm using the following `regular expression` to match 0 or more characters of any kind not including -,$,]

**Regex Expression:**

```
(.*[^\-\$\]])
```

Is this the correct expression for doing this? When I try it on the following string "hello-world" it doesn't seem to exclude the -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are matching any character *including those characters* an arbitrary number of times, followed by a single character that isn't one of those characters (i.e. your regex only dictates that those characters can't appear at the *end* of the string). You want this:

```
[^\-\$\]]*
```